# Jquery dialog form not posting field contents correctly to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datepicker

One of my web pages has a link on it.

```
<div id="updateDay"><a href="#" id = "updateDiffDay">Update</a> a different day</div>
```

When the user clicks the updateDiffDay link a jquery modal dialog box opens with a form on it.  The form has two fields, one is a datepicker and the other is a text box.

```
<form id="updateDiffDayForm" method="post" action="updateDiffDay.php">
    <input class = "field" type="text" placeholder= "Select a date" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" id="diffDayDailyMetric" class="field" placeholder="Enter weight" />
</form>
```

The dialog box has two buttons on it, Update and Cancel.  When the user clicks the Update button the form should post the content the user entered on the form to the updateDiffDay.php file.

The code for the modal dialog box is as follows:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
yearRange: "-90:+0"
  });

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 350,
  height: 250,
  modal: true,
  dialogClass: 'ui-dialog',
  draggable: false,
  resizable: false,
  buttons: {
        Update: function () {
    $('#updateDiffDayForm').submit();
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },

  show: {
    duration: 500
  },
  hide: {
    duration: 500
  }
});

$( "#updateDiffDay" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

});

The code for updateDiffDay.php is as follows:

```
<?php
$date = $_POST['datepicker'];
$metric = $_POST['diffDayDailyMetric'];
echo $date;
echo $metric;
```

Everything seems to work up until the fields in the form are posted to the PHP file. The problem is when the user clicks the Update button the content of the input boxes on the form (i.e., the date the user picks in the date picker and the value entered in the diffDayDailyMetric input box) are ignored and the default date for the datepicker, 1970-01-01, is posted to datepicker and  nothing is posted to diffDayDailyMetric.

I've tried a lot and searched the forums but haven't been able to make this work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is the first time I have ever used jquery like this.  Help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form:

```
<form id="updateDiffDayForm" method="post" action="updateDiffDay.php">
    <input class = "field" type="text" placeholder= "Select a date" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" id="diffDayDailyMetric" class="field" placeholder="Enter weight" />
</form>
```

You're not using a name attribute. Update it with:

```
<form id="updateDiffDayForm" method="post" action="updateDiffDay.php">
    <input class="field" type="text" placeholder="Select a date" id="datepicker" name="datepicker">
    <input type="text" id="diffDayDailyMetric" class="field" placeholder="Enter weight" name="diffDayDailyMetric" />
</form>
```

And that should do the trick.

Comment: Josh.  Thank you.  I thought it used the "id" not the "name".  I spent 4 hours trying to figure out what was wrong.  I made that change and it works perfectly.  Thanks again man!

Comment: No problem. I've done the same thing. It's never fun to debug.